# What is the regular expression for matching everything except two specific strings?

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression to match everything but two strings, STRING1 and STRING2.

This is what I tried:

`^(?!STRING1|STRING2).*$` is close, but it does not match STRING1X, which should be matched, because STRING1X is not equal to STRING1 and not equal to STRING2.

`^(?!STRING1|STRING2)$` doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?!STRING1$|STRING2$).*
```

Explanation:

`^` asserts the start of the string.

`(?!STRING1$|STRING2$)` is a negative lookahead assertion that excludes matches for the exact strings "STRING1" and "STRING2". The `$` anchor ensures that the match includes the entire string.

`.*` matches any character (except newline) zero or more times.